# How to make a class remove itself?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating a game over screen and there is a retry button on it, when that button is clicked, the game over screen remove itself. I tried "this.visible = false;" but it doesn't seems to work. When I first restart the game, it works fine, the game over screen is gone. But when I restart the game for the second time, the game over screen is here again, it just keeps coming back after the first restart! So how to make the retry button to check the game over screen is on stage and if so then remove it? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
package objects {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.*

public class GameOverMenu extends BaseMenu {

    public function GameOverMenu(stageRef: Stage = null) {
        this.stageRef = stageRef;
        btnRetry.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, returnSelectionMenu, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function returnSelectionMenu(e: MouseEvent): void {
        unload(new SelectionMenu(stageRef));
        this.visible = false;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695326/as3-error-2025-the-supplied-displayobject-must-be-a-child-of-the-caller

Comment: I feel it's the unload method...when I work with screen in games, I tend to only use the visible property. I never delete/unload screens. I see you are not using flash CC, where it's easier to use frames.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to replace it with frames (visible property), but still the same, it won't disappear after the first retry. And I'm using Flash CC.